# Authorization Basic headers not working in ionic 2

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, ionic2

How I set my headers. I looked all over the internet but when I send it to the server it doesn’t recognize my Authorization header. How did you solve that problem? I have User name or password and set header properly but did not work set header. Also response 401 error because header Authorization not set.

```
let username: string = 'username';
let password: string = 'password';
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

var url = "http://MYURL?grant_type=password&username="name"&password="pwd""
this.http.post(url, options)
.subscribe(res => {

console.log(res['_body']);

 }, (err) => {
    console.log("Somthing went wrong!"+err);
    });
```

Please resolve my issue how to get proper response. ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can resolve this issue if you are using HttpClient-

Create Option and Header Object like this-

```
let options: any = {};
options.headers = new HttpHeaders({ Accept: 'application/json', 
         Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password),
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
});
```

Then call POST method-

```
    var url = "http://MYURL?grant_type=password&username='name'&password='pwd'"
this.http.post(url, options)
.subscribe(res => {

console.log(res['_body']);

 }, (err) => {
    console.log("Somthing went wrong!"+err);
    });
```

Alos Notice the quotes for name and password in url.

Comment: I import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'; and use new HttpHeaders but again same issue 401.

Comment: Have you checked your url whether it's correct or not? Can you make call from postman or something and see the response?

Comment: Yes URL call in postman and set basic Auth username or password then get successfully response.

Comment: try in ionic serve. Open in browser and show alert popup YOUR CONNECTION TO THIS SITE IS NOT PRIVATE.  and show two textfield username or password. If enter correct username or password when get response successfully else enter incorrect username or password so get 401 error.

Comment: I want already set username or password in header. not required open popup.

Comment: Response with status: 401 OK for URL: http://nobodyyz.ddns.net:9999/dep/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=ankur&password=827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b

Comment: "Basic " + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(YOUR_USERNAME + ':' + YOUR_PASSWORD))), try this for Authorization header.

Comment: I am waiting for your response. P[lease solve my problem

Comment: It's hard to resolve your issue without knowing backend stuff and error. Might be some issue you are getting from server side. Check the logs from server side.

Comment: But same API working in android. and successfully authentication in user side. Please try ones.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how its working:**

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
```

headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));

Comment: change 

headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 

to

headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));

It will work